# Using other installers from install4j

Tags: install4j

I have different Installers and Uninstallers like innosetup astrum msi which Should be installed from install4j. I use the Componentinstall with executing the external installer by the java Processbuilder. The components are added with anttasks. Is there a  Way, which allows a complete rollback if One of the installer fails?

Answer (score 0):

To execute another installer, use the "Run executable or batch file" action.

For handling rollback, call the external uninstaller by selecting the "Use rollback executable" property and filling in the "Rollback executable" property of the action.